# screen sharing using java

Tags: java, swing, screensharing

I found this screen sharing code using java. This is the client side where it recieves the screen.

Client side :

```
    class ReceiveScreen extends Thread{
    private ObjectInputStream cObjectInputStream = null;
    private JPanel cPanel = null;
    private boolean continueLoop = true;
    InputStream oin = null;
    Image image1 = null;

    public ReceiveScreen(InputStream in,JPanel p){
        oin = in;
        cPanel = p;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            //Read screenshots of the client and then draw them
            while(continueLoop){
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*1024];
                int count = 0;
                do{
                    count+=oin.read(bytes,count,bytes.length-count);
                }while(!(count>4 && bytes[count-2]==(byte)-1 && bytes[count-1]==(byte)-39));

                image1 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                image1 = image1.getScaledInstance(cPanel.getWidth(),cPanel.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_FAST);

                //Draw the received screenshots

                Graphics graphics = cPanel.getGraphics();
                graphics.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, cPanel.getWidth(), cPanel.getHeight(), cPanel);
            }

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone explain what does this while condition do ?

> while(!(count>4 && bytes[count-2]==(byte)-1 &&
>   bytes[count-1]==(byte)-39));

to view [Server side](https://github.com/rajpushkar/Remote-Desktop-Control/blob/master/Server/SendScreen.java) .

Comment: It's checking the value of a couple of bytes. Or are you asking *why* those specific values?

Comment: "can anyone explain what does this while condition do?" Yeah. [Someone can](https://github.com/rajpushkar).

Comment: have you implemented screen sharing in java ? can u share any source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **It reads bytes from a socket, until there are at least 4 of them.**
2. **Then it checks the last two bytes for a magic number, signifying the end of an image.**
3. Then it creates the image object from the raw bytes.
4. Then it draws the image object to the screen.

(and it keeps repeating this until `continuteloop` is set to false.

You should learn DeMorgan's therom.  It permits the condition to be rewritten

```
while(!(count>4 && bytes[count-2]==(byte)-1 && bytes[count-1]==(byte)-39));
```

is the same as

```
while ( count < 4 || bytes[count-2] != (byte)-1 || bytes[count-1] != (byte)-39 );
```

Which makes the condition clearer.

- four bytes must be read
- the second to the last byte must be 0xFF
- the last byte must be 0xD9

If you look up the JPEG image specification format, you'll see that 0xFFD9 is a "JPEG Marker" which indicates the "end of an image stream"

So, this loop effectively reads a JPEG image from the socket, and displays it, until the `continuteloop` flag is set to false.